# Does exists a routine to perform Sensitivity analysis after weighting by inverse probability of treatment weight?

Tags: sample, propensity-scores, weights, survey-weights

I am employing a propensity score matching to get the treatment group and the control group balanced. I employ the inverse probability weights times some sampling weights (I am using a survey, hence I need to account for non-reponse bias). Then I estimate the effect weighting the outcome regression with these special weights.

Is there any method employed in a statistical routine (e.g., STATA, R) to perform a sensitivity analysis after IPW?

Thanks.